# Why won't my dog play with his toy anymore?

Tags: dogs, behavior, toys

My boyfriend has a little dog, named Thor, who absolutely loves to play. He has his favorite toy, named Blue (little blue piggy) that I gave him; and Poe (Poe from Kung Fu Panda) that my boyfriend gave him.

Before I moved in my boyfriend's apartment, his ex was living there and Thor would always play with his other toy, Squirtle; my boyfriend also got him this one. Now she's out of the picture and he never plays with that toy anymore.

Please tell me whether I should get rid of it and why he won't play with it.

Answer (score 2):

It's his toy, so keep it. He will play with it if he wants to. Maybe you can play with the toy and try to bring him in the play. It's natural for dogs to get bored with their toys, like a kid would. Just make sure you wash them every so often, so it can get fresh smells on it.

Hope this helps.